# abort/interrupt/kill long running cross sql select query in qt5

Tags: sql, interrupt, qt5, abort

I have searched Google for long but didn't found any solution to this problem, 
I just want to stop long running queries in Qt5 because if i use sqlite and there is an active long running query i can't do insert or update or delete queries either even if i use different threads this means whole program is stuck till query is completed. 
 
Before using qt i used wxwidgets with wxsqlite3 which had interrupt function aborting running queries. 
Mostly i will be using interrupt for viewing data in QTableView as user types like a live search on Google this means if there is long running select query it will be executed many times if i don't use interrupt. 
This will be useful for auto completion from database too but as above it will freeze if another query is running.
Although i know that there is no solution which will work on all sql servers but i only intend to support mysql, mssql, psql and sqlite3.
and if there is no solution at all i just want to know if i can call sqlite3_interrupt in Qt5.